# How to use the ROS tf listener to get the transform and apply it to my velocity data?

Tags: c++, ros

I have velocity data from the sensor, but somehow it is not in the robot body frame. It's been in a world frame, so it's not correct. So I need to transform it in the robot body frame as that how should be in the correct way. So I need a listener that will listen for transformations to be broadcast. Once broadcast I can use the listener to get the transform and apply it to your data.

I made a ROS nodes for broadcast and listener. But is still not correct the velocity. Here is the sensor data that include the linear velocity and its looks like this:

```
header: 
  seq: 182
  stamp: 
    secs: 39
    nsecs: 244000000
  frame_id: "world"
child_frame_id: "rexrov2/base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -0.0462157448086
      y: -0.0175201465699
      z: -18.7747349396
    orientation: 
      x: 0.00029722877228
      y: -0.000159403004117
      z: -0.00433868890864
      w: 0.999990530967
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: -0.00672636768741
      y: -0.00264084973057
      z: 0.204243325029
    angular: 
      x: -7.4723382137e-05
      y: -0.00310117164775
      z: -0.00108493763869
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Then the robot frame is `rexrov2/base_link`and the sensor is `rexrov2/pose_sensor_link_default`. The frame broadcaster is this one

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TwistStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h>


void poseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg){


 static tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster br;
 geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;

 transformStamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
 transformStamped.header.frame_id = "world";
 transformStamped.child_frame_id = "rexrov2/base_link";

 transformStamped.transform.translation.x = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
 transformStamped.transform.translation.y = msg->pose.pose.position.y;
 transformStamped.transform.translation.z = msg->pose.pose.position.z;

 transformStamped.transform.rotation.x = msg->pose.pose.orientation.x;
 transformStamped.transform.rotation.y = msg->pose.pose.orientation.y;
 transformStamped.transform.rotation.z = msg->pose.pose.orientation.z;
 transformStamped.transform.rotation.w = msg->pose.pose.orientation.w;

 br.sendTransform(transformStamped);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
 ros::init(argc, argv, "my_tf2_broadcaster");
 ros::NodeHandle node;
 ros::Subscriber sub = node.subscribe("rexrov2/pose_gt", 10, &poseCallback);

 ros::spin();
 return 0;
};
```

And the listener node is this one

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv){
 ros::init(argc, argv, "my_tf2_listener");

 ros::NodeHandle node;
 ros::Publisher robot_vel =node.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("robot/vel", 10);
 tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;
 tf2_ros::TransformListener tfListener(tfBuffer);

 ros::Rate rate(10.0);
 while (node.ok()){
   geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;
   try{
     transformStamped = tfBuffer.lookupTransform("rexrov2/base_link", "world", ros::Time(0)); 
      }
   catch (tf2::TransformException &ex) {
     ROS_WARN("%s",ex.what());
     ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
     continue;
                                       }

   geometry_msgs::Twist vel_msg;
   vel_msg.linear.x = 0.5 * sqrt(pow(transformStamped.transform.translation.x, 2) + pow(transformStamped.transform.translation.y, 2));

   robot_vel.publish(vel_msg);

   rate.sleep();
                 }
 return 0;
};
```

The sensor data that is not in the correct frame is published under `rexrov2/pose_gt` and the robot base link is `rexrov2/base_link`. The warnings I'm getting are:

```
[ WARN] [1635767328.332529320, 14554.020000000]: "rexrov2/pose_gt" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

Any help?Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The warning you are getting is because you don't have the TF frames connected. Please check them out with

```
rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree
```

It seems you are not publishing anywhere the transform between "rexrov2/pose_gt" and "rexrov2/base_link". So run this command in a separate terminal to publish the transform so your node can get it:

```
rosrun tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 rexrov2/pose_gt resrov2/base_link
```

If you stop receiving the warning running that command, it means that you need to include it in a launch file along with your node in order to run all at the same time

```xml
<launch>
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_gt_broadcaster" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 resrov2/base_link rexrov2/pose_gt" />
</launch>
```

And replace the transformation 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 (x y z qx qy qz qw) by the correct one

In addition to this, I don't see any subscriber in your code, but I think it's because you're using the node to do preliminar tests with the ROS integration

Comment: How should be the subscriber in your code? I should subscribe to `/rexrov2/pose_gt ` sensor data

Comment: what do you mean by : And replace the transformation 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 (x y z qx qy qz qw) by the correct one?

Comment: You don't need to subscribe to TF frames, that's what the transform listener is actually doing.

Comment: You need to replace the transform values to the real ones that you are using in your system, i.e. the coordinates transform between the reference frames

Comment: no. I mean to subscribe to the sensor topic data. I have a sensor velocity data but its in a world frame. I want to be in the robot_body frame. Understand?

Comment: I only want that sensor  velocity date to transform in the robot frame. I modified according your suggestion but velocity now is totally not correct. Its increase with the time. I edit the code and explain better in the question. Please can you see and help

Comment: with the code i actually get the translation (distance) in x direction and not velocity. What is wrong?

Comment: @Bob9710 transforms provide just what their name implies; transforms. They describe frame offsets relative to each other and not any sort of odometry data.

Comment: so transform divided by time(timestamp) should give me the correct velocity ?

Comment: Any way can you tell me what should change in the code that edit in order to get the correct velocity from the sensor data in the robot body frame? Thanks

Comment: would be this formula  `vel_linear = hypotenuse(xlast,ylast, transform.getOrigin().x(),transform.getOrigin().y()); ` `xlast = transform.getOrigin().x(); ylast = transform.getOrigin().y();` to get the velocity?

Comment: @Bob9710 I think you're asking two different questions here. Your original question is about why a transform to a sensor doesn't exist, which the above answer solves. Deducing velocity from a dynamic transform is possible, but not best practice. As well, the above is a static transform, as it should be for sensors connected to a robot. It doesn't change so you cannot calculate velocity from it.

Comment: ok the first is solve. But what I want is the velocity to body frame. Yes the sensor is connected to the robot but somehow doesn't give the correct velocity. So can you help me with the sensor velocity problem?So how to calculate velocity than?

Comment: @Bob9710 more info is needed to answer that. You say you have a sensor that produces velocity. If that velocity isn't correct then something is wrong with your sensor node. If the transform isn't correct you need to update the above code with the right `x y z qx qy qz qw` params.

Comment: I edit the sensor date in the question. The linear velocity part of the  sensor data instead to be in the robot body frame , its in the world frame. So that is not correct. I want to be velocity of the robot body frame. What other info is need it. I update the question. Please can you read the updated question and tell me if more info are need it to answer my question? Also we can have a private chat?

Comment: I have velocity sensor data as can see in my question. It is twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: -0.00672636768741
      y: -0.00264084973057
      z: 0.204243325029.  But the problem is that is not in the robot body frame. Please can help?

Comment: @Bob9710 in one of your nodes you're broadcasting a transform from `world` to `base_link`. You shouldn't be manually broadcasting that transform and it certainly shouldn't be equal to your odometry data.

Comment: sorry dont understand. can you explain that with a code?

Comment: please can help with the correct code?